# Store periods of availability in a database

Tags: database, postgresql, data-structures, database-design

I am looking for an efficient, structured, comparable and query-able way to store one to many availability slots over a 24 hour day.

I need e.g. to store that a person is available from 8 to 12 and from 13 to 17 o'clock (in 24h format).

Also I will need to store the opening times of an institution.

Eventually I need to query an overview of the availabilities of all persons throughout the opening times of an institution, and how many persons will be available for each hour of the day e.g.

What I came up with so far is the following:

To store availabilities, I chose an `int[]`, in couples, meaning from-to, represented as minutes of the day.

Examples:

```
[480,720,780,1020] // 08:00 - 12:00, 13:00 - 17:00
[480,1020]         // 08:00 - 17:00
[600,1200]         // 10:00 - 20:00
[495,615,660,810]  // 08:15 - 10:15, 11:00 - 13:30
```

The granularity of storage must be 15 minutes for now, but could be more or less, even down to the minute in the future.

The underlying table structure (PostgreSQL) would be like this:

```
create table institution (
    id uuid not null primary key,
    ...
    opening_times int[]
)

create table person (
    id uuid not null primary key,
    ...
    availability int[]
)
```

Is this a good choice?

Another option would be to store all the available slots down to the granularity:

```
[480,495,510,525]  // 08:00 - 09:00, meaning 08:00-08:15, 08:15-08:30, 08:30-08:45, 08:45-09:00
```

Note that here we don't store data in couples (from-to), but every value means "the slot starting at *value*, and lasting *granularity* is available. 8 - 9 o'clock corresponds to 4 slots of granularity (15 minutes).

This would have the advantage of having no gaps, probably facilitating calculations and queries, at the expense of using more data.

I think the last option would be better because it's probably easier to query.

Or are there other possibilities?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Note that I use Hibernate SQLQuery to fetch the data. Storing is done by persisting an Entity, which works good with array properties using a custom UserType. At UI-level, I use Polymer, thus JavaScript, which allows easy manipulation and displays of the data.

Comment: A range type (maybe even an array of ranges) might be a better fit.

Comment: Oracle has interval datatype. You can use a start time and an interval value in separate columns. Check if you have a similar datatype in postgresql.

Comment: `tsrange[]` , array of tsrange, may be better option for your requirement. You can store ranges in your column and query on them with ease. Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/rangetypes.html